# Compact iff the set is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

My real analysis textbook says that the set
$$[0,1] \cup (2,3]$$
has maximum and minimum, but it is not compact. At the same time, the Heine-Borel Theorem says that

> A subset $S$ of $\mathbb R$ is compact iff $S$ is closed and bounded.

To my inexperienced eyes, the set $[0,1] \cup (2,3]$ is bounded, hence its maximum and minimum, and is also closed $-$ therefore according to the theorem it should be compact. Please let me know why I get so wrong $-$ thank you.

Comment: $[0,1]\cup(2,3]$ is not closed, why do you think it is?

Comment: That is exactly the reason I would like to get help. All I know is that a set is closed if its complement is open. Let me know how to show that it is not closed. Thank you.

Comment: $2$ is in the complement, but for any ball of radius $\varepsilon>0$ around $2$, you can find an element not in the complement. Hence the complement is not open.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your set is bounded. But its not closed, since its complement is $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,2]\cup(3,+\infty)$, which is not open: $2$ belongs to it, but no open interval centered at $2$ is contained in it.

Comment: Thank you also for adding "compactness" to my posting's category.

Comment: I thought it was relevant.

Comment: Do you think that henceforth intuitively, I may look at the set as union of two sets, $[0,1]$ as a closed set and $(2,3]$ as open set, and therefore the union is open? Thank you again.

Comment: No. It is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. But let me make my question a bit more precise: Do you think that henceforth intuitively, I may look at the problem as union of two sets, $[0,1]$ as a closed set and $(2,3]$ as open set, and therefore their union "can not be said as closed"? Thank you again.

Comment: No, because $(2,3]$ is **not** open.  Besides, $[0,3]$ is closed, $(1,2)$ is open, and $[0,3]\cup(1,2)$ is closed too.